# Does the 3DR Solo support ROS?

Tags: ros, quadcopter, linux, parrot, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,  I'm looking into buying a quadrotor for computer vision research, and the Solo looks like a viable candidate.  However, I can't find whether or not ROS is usable with the Linux distribution that the Solo runs.  If it would take a significant amount of time to get ROS working properly, I'm not interested, but the Solo looks quite a bit more capable than the Parrot ArDrone or Bebop.  If you instead have a recommendation for an alternative quadrotor, that would also be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236579/does-the-3dr-solo-support-ros?/) by [Sam94](https://answers.ros.org/users/27117/sam94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2016-06-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those of you still interested, I managed to connect to the Solo using mavros.  I probably won't have a chance to test the flight capabilities for a while, but I was able to read imu and pressure data from the corresponding ROS topics. I used the following command to establish the connection.

roslaunch mavros apm.launch fcu_url:="udp://:14550@10.1.1.10:14555"

In order for this to work, you must install mavlink in addition to the mavros package.  Otherwise, the command will run, but it will not connect to the Solo.  I will edit this post with additional information when I get the chance.

---

Originally posted by [Sam94](https://answers.ros.org/users/27117/sam94/) with karma: 76 on 2016-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While this isn't an answer to your question and we should probably setup a better channel for questions for specific type of robots  (e.g. Drone) that run with ROS, I recommend to join an existing thread for now.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ros-sig-mav/BkmDnXzG2cg/vDpjcPHsCgAJ
Note that often there may be commercial posts.

You could also see a [list of ROS-supported UAVs](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots#UAVs) (it's manually updated and thus never be an exhaustive list).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam94](https://answers.ros.org/users/27117/sam94/) on 2016-06-10**:
Thanks for the quick answer.  I also talked with tech support at 3DR, but the person I talked with had never even heard of ROS, so I don't really think  much is going on with ROS and the Solo.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Skysense Planner](http://www.skysense.co/planner-launch) is an Open-Source web planner for MAVLink-based drones and MAVROS is part of our architecture. We're experimenting also with the 3DR SOLO drone, with mixed results.
In particular, we get tons of these warnings:

example: "[ WARN] [1473858171.706365027]: PR: request param #41 timeout, retries left 2, and 331 params still missing"

Anyone that can help us understand what's wrong?

Thank You
Michele

---

Originally posted by [micheda](https://answers.ros.org/users/27982/micheda/) with karma: 11 on 2016-09-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-09-14**:
For the new questions you should open a new one (otherwise you will get less answers).

**Comment by [Sam94](https://answers.ros.org/users/27117/sam94/) on 2016-09-15**:
I've seen the same issue.  I'm not sure what the solution is, 3DR might just have the Solo set up so that it doesn't send values for all of the data that mavros expects.

**Comment by [micheda](https://answers.ros.org/users/27982/micheda/) on 2016-09-16**:
thanks Sam. With qgroundcontrol you can get all parameters, so I think that it's some kind of limitation of MAVROS.

**Comment by [micheda](https://answers.ros.org/users/27982/micheda/) on 2016-09-16**:
opened a ticket:  https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/issues/600